# Consumir WebService no delphi

Tags: java, delphi, web-service

Criei um webservice REST utilizando JAVA, porém preciso fazer um client em Delphi consumir esse webservice, tentei fazer varias vídeo aulas que encontrei pelo google, mas nenhuma me foi útil.

criei um webservice simples para testar essa comunicação com delphi e WS REST, a ideia do WS é fazer um insert, update, delete e select bancos, o WS Funciona certinho com os testes que fiz, mas, para consumir no delphi que não da certo, primeiramente estou testando apenas o GET.

WS:

Obs1: Utilizei o netbeans para criar o WS.

Obs2: O metodo GET em questão é o @Path("Banco/get/{nome}", os outros metodos GET foram apenas testes para ver como funciona o WS.

Obs3: Acho que não é necessário eu colocar as classes com os métodos de insert, select e etc, caso seja, eu edito o post.

```
package ws;

import CTR.BancoCTR;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dao.BancoDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author 
 */
@Path("BancoWs")
public class BancoWs {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of BancoWs
     */
    public BancoWs() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of ws.BancoWs
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getJson() {
        return "meu primeiro webservice restfull";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/get/{nome}")
    public String getBanco(@PathParam("nome") String nome){
        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();
        BancoDAO banco = new BancoDAO();

        if (nome.equals("null")){
            lista = banco.listBanco(0, nome);
        }else{
            lista = banco.listBanco(1, nome);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/list")
    public String listBancos(){

        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();

        BancoCTR banco = new BancoCTR();
        banco.setBcoCodigo(1);
        banco.setBcoNome("Santander");

        lista.add(banco);

        banco.setBcoCodigo(2);
        banco.setBcoNome("Banco do Brasil");

        lista.add(banco);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/listBd")
    public String listBdBancos(){

        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();

        BancoDAO dao = new BancoDAO();
        lista = dao.listBanco(0, "");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of BancoWs
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

Client:

a tela é bem simples:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

o pesquisar eu queria fazer em uma dbgrid, porém um exemplo que achei utilizava memo, então, tentei utiliza-lo para ver se dava certo e depois tentaria pela dbgrid, porem quando eu clica no botão pesquisar, ele limpa o memo mas não traz nenhuma informação e fica em branco, alterei diversas vezes o código, mas, sem sucesso o código atual esta pela metade, pois estava fazendo um exemplo e percebi no meio que não servia(eu acho) kkkkk.

Obs: Estou utilizando Delphi XE8.

```
procedure TForm1.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 filtro: String;
 mymarshal: TJSONUnMarshal;
begin
  rstrqst1.Resource := '/Banco/get/{nome}';
  rstrqst1.Method := rmGet;

  if edt3.Text <> '' then
    filtro := edt3.Text
  else
    filtro := 'null';

  rstrqst1.Params.AddUrlSegment('nome', filtro);
  rstrqst1.Execute;
  mymarshal := TJSONUnMarshal.Create;




  mmo1.Clear;
  mmo1.Lines.Add(rstrspns1.);
end;
```

infelizmente até agora não encontrei mais nenhum exemplo que possa seguir, encontrei alguns componentes como idHttp ou TFDStanStorageJSONLink, mas, fiquei na duvida se serviam, então resolvi perguntar aqui.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eu uso largamente nas minhas aplicações o IdFtp, ele tem em atendido em tudo hoje que precisei em Rest. Segue abaixo um exemplo enxuto de código que eu uso:

```
var
  http           : TIdHTTP;  
  AStrResponse   : TStringStream;
  oSSL           : TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;  
  FURL           : String;
begin
  Result:= FALSE;

  http:= TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  oSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(nil);

    oSSL.SSLOptions.Method      := sslvSSLv23;
    oSSL.SSLOptions.Mode        := sslmUnassigned;
    oSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode  := [];
    oSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    oSSL.host                   := '';

    http.IOHandler       := oSSL;

    http.HandleRedirects := TRUE;

    http.request.ContentType := 'application/json';

    FURL := 'http://a_sua_url.com/alguma_coisa'

    AStrResponse := TStringStream.Create;

    http.Get(FURL, AStrResponse);
    Response.Text := AStrResponse.DataString;

    FreeAndNil(AStrResponse);

    http.Disconnect;

  FreeAndNil(oSSL);
  FreeAndNil(http);

end;
```