# Consulta no webservice e populado uma grid com os dados

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe8

A pergunta referente a "duplicada", é sobre consumir o webservice em delphi, e neste caso eu já consumi, porém agora preciso jogar os dados que o delphi pega do webservice e colocar em uma grid, portanto, um pergunta bem diferente.

tenho um webservice REST feito em Java que faz uma consulta em uma tabela Banco, primeiramente joguei os dados em um MEMO para testar o webservice, porém, agora eu preciso jogar esses dados da consulta em uma grid, pesquisei no google e não encontrei nada que puderia me ajudar, então resolvi peguntar aqui no forum.

basicamente estou fazendo uma app simples para testar o funcionamento do delphi + WS REST, estou tentando criar um WS que faz um insert, update, delete e select nessa tabela Banco, primeiramente estou testando apenas os GETs.

WS:

Obs.1: O método get em questão é o `public String getBanco(@PathParam("nome") String nome)` o resto são apenas testes.
Obs.2: Acho que não é necessário colocar a classe com os métodos que realiza a pesquisa no banco, se caso seja, editarei o post.

```
package ws;

import CTR.BancoCTR;
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import dao.BancoDAO;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Context;
import javax.ws.rs.core.UriInfo;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PUT;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

/**
 * REST Web Service
 *
 * @author Vitor
 */
@Path("BancoWs")
public class BancoWs {

    @Context
    private UriInfo context;

    /**
     * Creates a new instance of BancoWs
     */
    public BancoWs() {
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves representation of an instance of ws.BancoWs
     * @return an instance of java.lang.String
     */
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String getJson() {
        return "meu primeiro webservice restfull";
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/get/{nome}")
    public String getBanco(@PathParam("nome") String nome){
        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();
        BancoDAO banco = new BancoDAO();

        if (nome.equals("null")){
            lista = banco.listBanco(0, nome);
        }else{
            lista = banco.listBanco(1, nome);
        }

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/list")
    public String listBancos(){

        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();

        BancoCTR banco = new BancoCTR();
        banco.setBcoCodigo(1);
        banco.setBcoNome("Santander");

        lista.add(banco);

        banco.setBcoCodigo(2);
        banco.setBcoNome("Banco do Brasil");

        lista.add(banco);

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Path("Banco/listBd")
    public String listBdBancos(){

        List<BancoCTR> lista = new ArrayList<BancoCTR>();

        BancoDAO dao = new BancoDAO();
        lista = dao.listBanco(0, "");

        Gson gson = new Gson();
        return gson.toJson(lista);
    }

    /**
     * PUT method for updating or creating an instance of BancoWs
     * @param content representation for the resource
     */
    @PUT
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public void putJson(String content) {
    }
}
```

No Delphi:

```
procedure TForm1.btnPesquisarClick(Sender: TObject);
var
 filtro: String;

 http: TIdHTTP;
 AStrResponse: TStringStream;
 oSSL: TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL;
 FURL: String;
begin

  if edt3.Text <> '' then
    filtro := edt3.Text
  else
    filtro := 'null';

  http := TIdHTTP.Create(Nil);
  oSSL := TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL.Create(Nil);

    oSSL.SSLOptions.Method := sslvSSLv23;
    oSSL.SSLOptions.Mode := sslmUnassigned;
    oSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyMode := [];
    oSSL.SSLOptions.VerifyDepth := 0;
    oSSL.Host := '';

    http.IOHandler := oSSL;
    http.HandleRedirects := True;
    http.Request.ContentType := 'application/json';

    FURL := 'http://localhost:8080/bancoWS/webresources/BancoWs/Banco/get/'
      + filtro;

    AStrResponse := TStringStream.Create;
    http.Get(FURL, AStrResponse);

    mmo1.Clear;
    mmo1.Lines.Add(AStrResponse.DataString);

    FreeAndNil(AStrResponse);
    http.Disconnect;

    FreeAndNil(oSSL);
    FreeAndNil(http);
end;
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Consumir WebService no delphi](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/273562/consumir-webservice-no-delphi)

Comment: creio que não, ja que ai eu pergunto sobre consumir webservice e não sobre carregar uma grid com os dados do webservice, o que fazer se as classes são as mesmas? kkk

Comment: tem um video aqui que mostra. Talves pode ajudar vc. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HJJSWMTpJvk

Comment: não me ajuda, pois, eu já estou consumindo o webservice e carregando os dados em uma MEMO (igual no vídeo) o meu problema agora é em vez de carregar esses dados em uma MEMO eu quero carrega-los em uma DBGrid.

Answer (score 1):

Para este fim utilizo a biblioteca [delphi-rest-client-api](https://github.com/fabriciocolombo/delphi-rest-client-api/), com ela é possível carregar um JSON para um dataset.

Segue o exemplo do criador:

```
var
  vDataSet: TClientDataSet;
begin
  vDataSet := TClientDataSet.Create(nil);
  try
    TDataSetUtils.CreateField(vDataSet, ftInteger, 'id');
    TDataSetUtils.CreateField(vDataSet, ftString, 'name', 100);
    TDataSetUtils.CreateField(vDataSet, ftString, 'email', 100);
    vDataSet.CreateDataSet;

    RestClient.Resource(CONTEXT_PATH + 'persons')
              .Accept(RestUtils.MediaType_Json)
              .GetAsDataSet(vDataSet);
  finally
    vDataSet.Free;
  end;
```